# Akka Stream from within a Spark Job to write into kafka

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, akka-stream

Willing to be the most efficient in writing data back into kafka, i am interested in using Akka Stream to write my RDD partition back into Kafka.

The problem is that i need a way to create an actor system per executor and not per partition which would be ridiculous. One may end up with 8 actorSystems on one node on one JVM. However having a Stream per partition is fine.

Has anyone already done that ?

> My understanding, an actor system can't be serialized, hence can't be
>   sent has broadcast variable which would be per executor.

If one has had the experience around figuring a solution to that and tested please would you share ?

Else i can always fall back to https://index.scala-lang.org/benfradet/spark-kafka-writer/spark-kafka-0-10-writer/0.3.0?target=_2.11 but i am not sure it is the most efficient way.

Comment: It would be interesting to see performance comparisons between using a vanilla kafka producer and using Akka streams. I can't see a strong reason why one would go significantly faster than the other.

Comment: My assumption is that, you benefit from the reactive stream feature, which in essence is supposed to be more dynamic and therefore faster. Less blocking. I have no idea how one would implement the back pressure and all with the original producer. it is just more work

Comment: The Kafka producer implements internally a buffering mechanism to optimize throughput. When on the writing side, I don't see any of the benefits mentioned: no need for back-pressure: Kafka is usually fast enough to accept any load give a proper dimensioning. Blocking: Not really an issue with buffering and I think you want still to wait until the write is done in order to continue and commit offsets of done work. From far, it looks like a no-win optimization.  But I guess that numbers win on opinions, so it would be interesting to see a comparison.

Comment: I see yes you are right, would be nice to see if actually akka-stream-kafka add something other than connecting to a stream in a larger picture

Comment: I have no idea of the internal and buffering capability of Kafka Producer

Comment: Which API would you recommend aside from the bare java one. Do you know the one called spark-kafka-writer, have you evaluated it ?

Comment: If you mean this: https://github.com/BenFradet/spark-kafka-writer I've used it several times with positive results. It's just the kafka API with a correctly applied per-partition execution (like the answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always define a global lazy val with an actor system:

```
object Execution {
  implicit lazy val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem()
  implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()
}
```

Then you just import it in any of the classes where you want to use Akka Streams:

```
import Execution._

val stream: DStream[...] = ...

stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  ...
  rdd.foreachPartition { records =>
    val (queue, done) = Source.queue(...)
      .via(Producer.flow(...))
      .toMat(Sink.ignore)(Keep.both)
      .run()  // implicitly pulls `Execution.materializer` from scope,
              // which in turn will initialize `Execution.actorSystem`

    ... // push records to the queue

    // wait until the stream is completed
    Await.result(done, 10.minutes)
  }
}
```

The above is kind of pseudocode but I think it should convey the general idea.

This way the system is going to be initialized on every executor JVM only once when it is needed. Additionally you can make the actor system "daemonic" in order for it to shut down automatically when the JVM finishes:

```
object Execution {
  private lazy val config = ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.daemonic = on")
    .withFallback(ConfigFactory.load())
  implicit lazy val actorSystem: ActorSystem = ActorSystem("system", config)
  implicit lazy val materializer: Materializer = ActorMaterializer()
}
```

We're doing this in our Spark jobs and it works flawlessly.

This works without any kind of broadcast variables, and, naturally, can be used in all kinds of Spark jobs, streaming or otherwise. Because the system is defined in a singleton object, it is guaranteed to be initialized only once per JVM instance (modulo various classloader shenanigans, but it doesn't really matter in the context of Spark), therefore even if some of the partitions get placed onto the same JVM (maybe in different threads), it will only initialize the actor system one time. `lazy val` ensures the thread-safety of the initialization, and `ActorSystem` is thread-safe, so this won't cause problems in this regard as well.

Comment: Oh thanks. Let me understand it a bit better. So you do not use broadcast variable at all ? could you give a bit more context code, how do you use the Execution object in your spark operation. I want to use it in spark streaming, i am not sure if i will have a new actor system per RDD or as you put it, for the time of the JVM. Can you help clarify a little. What is your context, spark streaming job or normal spark job.

Comment: I've expanded my answer, hopefully it answers your questions now.

Comment: How do you stop the stream, do you use take with the size of records ?

Comment: Also do you await for the termination of the stream as well, blocking that particular thread until the job is done ? or you just move on

Comment: These are actually completely different questions, so I suggest you to create new topics for them. I can't provide exact code, but we manually feed the queue materialized from the stream with the data in the microbatch RDDs, and we close the stream manually when the RDDs are exhausted. Not sure what do you mean about waiting for the termination of the stream and size of records.

Comment: Vladimir, thank you so far, and i understand about the code thing, but i think it is still possible to explain in words what is happening ? I think we are still in the question. Indeed, understanding how to handle a stream in a spark action basically. I think the main issue for me is that for instance as soon as you give whatever to source.Queue(), how do you know when you are done, how does the stream get completed. I have seen people, using "take" or "limit" and i have used it myself.

Comment: I could say, take () up to the size of the partition. The stream will terminate automatically. However, the problem i see is that "foreachPartition" will return immediatly, has the stream return a future. That is why i am asking, do you wait on your future returned by the stream, within the foreach operation ?

Comment: Vladimir. My apologies. I got confused in the process and really forgot how source. Queue works.

Comment: I see what do you mean now. If you use `Sink.ignore`, it will materialize into a `Future[NotUsed]` which will be completed when the stream completes. Then we use `Await.result` on this future to wait until the processing completes. I've updated my answer to show this approach.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just one the record I don't think source.queue is necessary here. Source.fromIterator  is better, so you don't have to push the record yourself and handle the backpressure scenario. Source.Apply would better to. Source.Queue would force you to handle backPressure yourself. Unless i am missing something, why do you prefere source.queue ?

Comment: Unfortunately, `fromIterator` simply won't work because Spark iterators rely on some thread-local context which is not set in the thread pool used by Akka. We found it out in a hard way.

Comment: Oh gosh thanks you saved me time. What about apply? Source(list(...)) did you try ? Same thing ?

Comment: `Source(List(..))` (or more like `Source(records.toVector)` or something similar) doesn't make sense in `foreachPartition` because it would require collecting the entire partition in memory. This is not feasible for us, but I think it should work if you know that your partitions are small.